# PHP Database Code Not Outputting Anything

Tags: php, web, mysqli

I'm getting no output. I can print_r the $_POST array and also echo it. I'm trying to output a name field from my database. The value is based on an id number specified using an HTML form.

I tried this code:

```
<?php
include 'database.php';
print_r($_POST);
echo $_POST['identification'];
$query = $con->prepare("SELECT name, email FROM crud WHERE id=?"); // prepate a query
$query->bind_param('s', $_POST['identification']); // binding parameters via a safer way than via direct insertion into the query. 'i' tells mysql that it should expect an integer.
$query->execute(); // actually perform the query
$result = $query->get_result(); // retrieve the result so it can be used inside PHP
$r = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC); // bind the data from the first result row to $r
echo $r['name']; // will return the price
?>
```

Please help

Comment: What does `var_dump($r);` show?

Comment: Either error in the query or there is no match for such value

Comment: array(1) { ["identification"]=> string(1) "2" }

Comment: I suppose you added `var_dump($r);`, but don't see its output. Then you need to add this line at the top of your script: `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and run it again. It should tell you what's the problem with your query

Comment: Is your `id` column _really_ a string? The comment on the end of the `bind_param` line talks about using `i` rather than `s`, should you be doing that instead?

Comment: @droopsnoot makes absolutely not difference (well, unless its absurdly big bigint)

Comment: @everyone I was querying empty rows. The PHP code I got works. I also changed s to i within bind_param

Comment: @YourCommonSense fair enough, I use PDO so don't have that much knowledge on mysqli, I figured that if specifying the parameter types was necessary, then it might make a difference.